# How can I get the height of a given string's descender?

Tags: android

How can I get the height of a given string's descender?

[image]

For instance,

- `abc` should return 0.
- `abcl` should return 0.
- `abcp` should return distance from descnder line to baseline.
- `abclp` should return distance from descnder line to baseline.

The best I could came out so far is

```
private int getDecender(String string, Paint paint) {
    // Append "l", to ensure there is Ascender
    string = string + "l";
    final String stringWithoutDecender = "l";

    final Rect bounds = new Rect();
    final Rect boundsForStringWithoutDecender = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(string, 0, string.length(), bounds);
    paint.getTextBounds(stringWithoutDecender, 0, stringWithoutDecender.length(), boundsForStringWithoutDecender);
    return bounds.height() - boundsForStringWithoutDecender.height();
}
```

However, my code smell is that they are not good enough. Is there any better and faster way?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I was looking for the same functionality. It turns out there is much simpler way,
you do not even need separate function for that.

If you just call getTextBounds() on a given string, the returned bounding box will already have that information.

For example:

```
paint.getTextBounds(exampleString1 , 0, exampleString1.length(), bounds);

if (bounds.bottom > 0) Log.i("Test", "String HAS descender");
else Log.i("Test", "String DOES NOT HAVE descender");
```

Simply saying bounds.top tells you the ascent of the string (it has negative value as Y axis 0 point is at the baseline of the string) and bounds.bottom tells you the descent of the string (which can be 0 or positive value for strings having descent).

Comment: There's something interesting going on here. When I use this to test the string "abcd", the resulting `bounds.bottom` rect is 1. When I test with "abcp", the bottom is 3. So there's always a descender? Except wait, if I test with "A" or "AB", the descender is 0. "ABC" is 1. "a", "ab" are 1, "h" is 0. Seems like a lot of characters have a non-zero descender....

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look at [Paint.FontMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html). The descent member will give you "The recommended distance below the baseline for singled spaced text.".

Comment: The question how to find out, is there any character with non-zero descent within given string.

Comment: Sorry, I read too quickly. You probably have the best solution in your code.